# Mocked npm module returns empty objects in jest

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm following [this guide](https://medium.com/free-code-camp/testing-socket-io-client-app-using-jest-and-react-testing-library-9cae93c070a3) in a TypeScript environment. My aim is to mock the `socket.io-client` implementation in my tests so that I can simulate socket events in an instant messaging component.

```
// __mocks__/socket.io-client.js

// SOURCE: https://medium.com/free-code-camp/testing-socket-io-client-app-using-jest-and-react-testing-library-9cae93c070a3

let EVENTS = {};
function emit(event, ...args) {
  EVENTS[event].forEach(func => func(...args));
}
const socket = {
  on(event, func) {
    if (EVENTS[event]) {
      return EVENTS[event].push(func);
    }
    EVENTS[event] = [func];
  },
  emit,
};

export const io = {
  connect() {
    return socket;
  },
};

// Additional helpers, not included in the real socket.io-client,just for out test.
// to emulate server emit.
export const serverSocket = { emit };

// cleanup helper
export function cleanup() {
  EVENTS = {};
}
export default io;
```

I have a socket wrapper in my code with some convenience methods, among them this snippet:

```
// SocketWrapper.ts
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

/* Code removed for brevity */

    console.log(io);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(io));

    this.socket = io.connect(
```

When I run my tests, I receive the following error:

```
 FAIL  src/components/User/components/Messages/Messages.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: io.connect is not a function

      55 |     console.log(JSON.stringify(io));
      56 | 
    > 57 |     this.socket = io.connect(


      at MessagesService.connect (src/lib/classes/SocketWrapper.ts:69:19)
      at MessagesService.connect (src/services/Messages.service.ts:29:11)
      at new MessagesService (src/services/Messages.service.ts:25:10)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/User/components/Messages/Messages.tsx:9:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/User/User.tsx:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/testUtils/pages/UserPage.tsx:10:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/User/components/Messages/Messages.test.tsx:2:1)

  console.log src/lib/classes/SocketWrapper.ts:54
    { cleanup: [Function: cleanup],
      io: { connect: [Function: connect] },
      serverSocket: { emit: [Function: emit] },
      default: { connect: [Function: connect] } }

  console.log src/lib/classes/SocketWrapper.ts:55
    {"io":{},"serverSocket":{},"default":{}}
```

As you can see in the logs when I log the module as a string, the mock returns empty objects instead of my mocked implementation. I've looked everywhere but can't seem to find a solution for this.

Comment: Try using `import io from 'socket.io-client'` instead of using `import * as io from 'socket.io-client'`

Comment: @slideshowp2 that was it! Care to explain why this happens? Also, feel free to add this as your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

> The name parameter is the name of the "module object" which will be used as a kind of namespace to refer to the exports. The export parameters specify individual named exports, while the import * as name syntax imports all of them.

That means if you use `import * as io from 'socket.io-client'`, the `io` is a kind of namespace.

In your mock file, the `io` is an object and `export default io;`

If you use `import * as io from 'socket.io-client'`. The value of `io` variable will be:

```js
{ // <- the outer object is io namespace
  io: { // <- this is the io object you defined in your mock file
    connect() {
      return socket;
    }
  }
}
```

Use `import io from 'socket.io-client'`, it will import the default object from it which is:

```js
const io = {
  connect() {
    return socket;
  },
};
```

If you insist using `import * as io from 'socket.io-client'` statement.
 Change

```js
export const io = {
  connect() {
    return socket;
  },
};
```

To:

```
export function connect() {
  return socket;
}
```

And remove `export default io;` statement.